# Error while implementing facebook-sdk-swift, app crashes in AppDelegate

Tags: swift, facebook

When I add `SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)` to `application(_, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method in AppDelegate, the app crashes with error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableData
>   isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x600000054340'

Without it the app runs fine. I also tried Objective-C version of the SDK as well, however I get the same error with the respective method call:

```
FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
```

Comment: have you tried debugging the issue? The error states, that you are trying to send the `isEqualToString` message to `NSData`, what is wrong type of object. It should be `NSString`. Do you know how to enable `exception breakpoints` in your project?

Comment: I did add an exception breakpoint...

Comment: can you show the line where the exception is being thrown from?

Comment: if (![dict[kFBSDKAccessTokenUUIDKey] isEqualToString:uuid]) {... in classFBSDKAccessTokenCacheV4.m

Comment: so it is crashing in the framework, not in your code?

Comment: Yes, I guess so

Comment: Seeing the same issue. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with version 4.18.0 Facebook SDK. I reverted to an older version 4.17.0 and I no longer get the crash.